# Best way to count subset of array elements

Tags: c#, arrays

What is the best way to count the number of numeric elements within a string where the elements are delimited by `'/'`?

For example, in the string `"OL/12/15/NR/17/21"`, we have 4 numeric elements. The only non-numeric (i.e. `alpha`) elements that can be found in the array are `"OL"` (off ladder) and `"NR"` (no result).

This is my solution but I suspect that there are better, more efficient algorithms:

```
int cnt = 0;
string sampleString = "OL/12/15/NR/17/21";
string[] sampleArray = sampleString.split('/');

foreach (string element in sampleArray)
    if (element != "OL" && element != "NR")
        cnt++;
```

Comment: try regular expression that is good way to find easily, try my answer ..there is no need to hard code any thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternate option with LINQ:

```
string[] sampleArray = sampleString.Split(new Char[]{'/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int strCount = sampleArray.Count(x=> x!= "OL" && x != "NR");
```

This would be shorter but can't say this one is efficient, [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3diLYr) you can find a working example to prove this:

Comment: @RufusL: Yep you are correct, I have added a link to prove your comment

Comment: No doubt this is efficient way but still that's not a good approach to your problem. Use Regular Expression instead.

Comment: I did a quick Stopwatch test & found this is faster than regex surprisingly.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex to match numbers:

```
string sampleString = "OL/12/15/NR/17/21";
int count = Regex.Matches(sampleString,@"\b\d+\b").Count;
```

Comment: how come its "\d+" that is stand for digit, you can check it here : regex101.com/r/iI1wQ7/3 , Please correct me if i am wrong some where

Comment: This regular expression does not cater for the scenario where the first element in the string is numeric.

Comment: You're right. But this answer is just to give you a better approach. However I updated the answer.

Comment: @MUT - sorry to say but you can go to link i given and check it , you can run code in visual studio and chck...bet not to put -1 without checking it...just to get more points

Comment: Output of my program aslo given by me ..run my code in visual studio and check ...and let me know if it matching alphanumeric ....

Comment: Test `"OL/12/15/NR1231231/17/21"`.

Comment: have you tried in visual studio ............language is C# and editor is visual studio ...i hope you know how to use Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer some generic method like this:

```
int cnt = 0;
string sampleString = "OL/12/15/NR/17/21";
string[] sampleArray = sampleString.split('/');
int numValue;

foreach (string element in sampleArray)
    if (Int32.TryParse(element , out numValue))
        cnt++;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of regular expression , below is full code for you

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(\d+)";
        string input = @"OL/12/15/NR/17/21";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output of my working code

- '12' found at index 3.
- '15' found at index 6.
- '17' found at index 12.
- '21' found at index 15.

here is demo for the same : https://regex101.com/r/iI1wQ7/3

Comment: Your pattern will also matches the number with alphabets. e.g `@"OL/12/15/NR1234/17/21"`. In this case number of matches is `5` but it should be `4`

Comment: @MUT - how come its "\d+" that is stand for digit, you can check it here : https://regex101.com/r/iI1wQ7/3

Comment: It matches the digit but `\d` is not equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: @MUT - sorry to say but you can go to link i given and check it , you can run code in visual studio and chck...bet not to put -1 without checking it...just to get more points